# Add optgroup to existing select using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an existing select:

```
var $selectStatus = jQuery("<select id='Status' name='status'></select>");
var enabledHtml = "<option value='ENABLED'>"ON"</option>";
var disabledHtml = "<option value='DISABLED'>"OFF"</option>";
var $statusEnabled = jQuery(enabledHtml);
var $statusDisabled = jQuery(disabledHtml);
//some code to add "selected" properties
...
//finally add to select
$selectStatus.append($statusEnabled, $statusDisabled);
```

This produces a select with ON/OFF as the options. Now I want to add an optgroup along with some values I've got stored in an array.

So what you should get is a select something like:

```
<select>
    <option value="ENABLED">ON</option>
    <option value="DISABLED">OFF</option>
  <optgroup label="Info">
    <option value="some value">some value</option>
    <option value="some value">some value</option>
...
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

It could be an empty optgroup with no option values or any number of option values.

I tried this:

```
var status_optgroup_open = "<optgroup label='Info'>"
    for(i=0;i<info.length;i++) 
    {
        $foobar = jQuery('#Status').append(jQuery('<option/>').val(info[i].info_name).html(info[i].info_name));

    }
    var status_optgroup_close = "</optgroup>"

var $statusOpen = jQuery(status_optgroup_open);
var $statusClose = jQuery(status_optgroup_close);
$selectStatus.append($statusEnabled, $statusDisabled, $statusOpen, $foobar, $statusClose);
```

The output of info[i].info_name is what I expect but I'm just not sure how do I append them in this context. Right now this just yields an empty optgroup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function does not merely concatenate all of the strings passed into it.

So this: `$("body").append("<p>","hi","</p>")` will not yield `<p>hi</p>`

Instead, it will take each element in the array, add them to the DOM if necessary, and add those elements to the parent.  So the actual output would look like this:

```html
<p></p>
"hi"
<p></p>
```

Instead, what you want to do, is create the `optgroup` and append all of the individual options to that.  And then add that entire object (children and all) to the select element like this:

```js
var info = [
  {info_name: 'Some Value 1'},
  {info_name: 'Some Value 2'}
];

// create select
var $selectStatus = $("<select id='Status' name='status'>");

// create options
var enabled = "<option value='ENABLED'>ON</option>";
var disabled = "<option value='DISABLED'>OFF</option>";

// create opt group
var $optgroup = $("<optgroup label='Info'>");
for (i=0; i<info.length; i++) {
  var op = "<option value='" + info[i].info_name + "'>" + info[i].info_name + "</option>";
  $optgroup.append(op);
}

// create select
$selectStatus.append(enabled, disabled, $optgroup);

// add select to page
$("body").append($selectStatus);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
```

**Note**: jQuery will automatically create DOM elements from strings provided in the [jQuery constructor](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2) `$(<html>)`.  Meaning it isn't necessary to close elements tags that pass into the `$()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a string and append that:

```
var optgroup = "<optgroup label='Info'>";

for (var i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
    name = info[i].info_name;
    optgroup += "<option value='" + name + "'>" + name + "</option>"
}

optgroup += "</optgroup>"

$('select').append(optgroup);
```